# How to retain the wireless settings using ndiswrapper

Tags: 11.10, wireless, laptop, ndiswrapper

I have an older laptop and Ubuntu does not have drivers for my wireless PCMCIA card.  So I found the Windows drivers and loaded them with `ndiswrapper` via the Windows Wireless Drivers utility app. I can load the drivers and the card then works fine... no problems at all. The problem is to keep these settings once the machine is shut down or rebooted.  At present, the settings are lost if this is done and I have to reinstall the wireless driver every time. I have tried various suggestions on how to keep the settings but so far none of them have worked.

There has to be a configuration file somewhere that contains the wireless setup info but I do not know what or where it is.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! [Just so you know](http://askubuntu.com/revisions/101359/1), tags help us categorize questions so people experiencing the same issue (or those who are more knowledgeable about such things) can more quickly locate your question and any answers posted.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into similar problems in the past trying to get a Linksys WUSB54G to work with ubuntu. I found this tutorial really helpful: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper
It talks about your exact problem in section 3.6.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.